# Internet not working after connecting to OpenVPN CE with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: openvpn

I have installed OpenVPN Community Edition with Ubuntu 18.04. Once OpenVPN is connected I am unable to connect with internet and other websites. Please check my `Client.conf` and `Server.conf` below and let me know if anything causing issue.

## Client.conf

```
client
dev tap
#dev tun
#proto tcp
proto udp
remote 52.19.26.62 1194
remote-random-hostname
#remote 52.19.26.62 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
#auth-retry none
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
tls-client
tls-auth pfs.key
auth-user-pass
auth-nocache
#redirect-gateway def1
reneg-sec 0
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
```

## server.conf

```
port 1194
#port 443
proto udp
dev tap
#proto tcp
#dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh2048.pem
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
#push "redirect-gateway local def1"
push "redirect-gateway local def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append openvpn.log
verb 3
tls-server
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pfs.key
```

Also, when added `up/down update-systemd-resolved` and trying to connect OpenVPN Connect I am getting below error even though the script is exist in respective folder (`/etc/openvpn/scripts`)
Error:

```
Options error: --up script fails with '/etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved': No such process (errno=3)
Options error: Please correct this error.
Use --help for more information.
```

Could you please guide me to fix the issue? To connect with OpenVPN and internet connected.

Comment: Could you please clean up your post? it's quite unreadable in its current form.